# Python Kivy: Create a FloatLayout with access to Setting panel and running command

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I'm currently trying to learn while using the Kivy GUI language.
I'm trying to create a layout with different widget on it (button, file browser ...) with one of the button accessing a custom Setting panel to set some parameters and then a button to run a command using these parameters.

I'm having trouble to get the command button working and it is probably a simple object oriented problem but I can't see what's wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Also if anyone have an idea how to use the command button ( btn) to access some of the values stored from the settings it would be great.

Here is my code so far:

# main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from settingsjson import settings_json

Builder.load_string('''
<Interface>:
    Button:
        text: 'Analysis Settings'
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, 'y': 0.3}
        on_release: app.open_settings()
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2

''')                               

class Interface(FloatLayout):       #
    pass


class SettingsApp(App):
    def build(self):

        #Color setting#
        blue = (0, 0, 1.5, 2.5)

        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        setting = self.config.get('example', 'boolexample')

        btn = Button(text='Run!',
                     background_color=blue,
                     size_hint=(.2, .2),
                     pos_hint={'x':.5, 'y':.3})
        btn.bind(on_press=self.command1)
        Interface.add_widget(Interface.btn)

        return Interface()

    def command1(self, event):
        print("button touched")

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('example', {
            'boolexample': True,
            'numericexample': 10,
            'optionexample': 'Analysis type1',
            'stringexample': 'PO12345'})

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Parameter of Analysis',
                                self.config,
                                data=settings_json)

    def on_config_change(self, config, section,
                         key, value):
        print config, section, key, value

SettingsApp().run()
```

settings.ini

```
[example]
boolexample = 1
optionexample = Analysis type1
stringexample = 46464, hdfhf, jhdgfjhf, hjdgfjhf
numericexample = 455
optionsexample = Analysis type2
```

#### settingsjson.py

```
import json

settings_json = json.dumps([
    {'type': 'title',
     'title': 'Analysis parameters'},
    {'type': 'bool',
     'title': 'Add accessin number list?',
     'desc': 'Choose if you want to add an Accession list to your analysis',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'boolexample'},
    {'type': 'numeric',
     'title': 'Select maximum number of protei to display',
     'desc': 'This will determine maximum protein displayed on graph',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'numericexample'},
    {'type': 'options',
     'title': 'Selection your Analysis option',
     'desc': 'Choose for an analysis option',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'optionsexample',
     'options': ['Analysis type1', 'Analysis type2', 'Analysis type3']},
    {'type': 'string',
     'title': 'Type specific accession number to display',
     'desc': 'Type some accession numbers to display',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'stringexample'}])
```

Comment: *Also if anyone have an idea how to use the command button ( btn) to access some of the values stored from the settings it would be great.*--See my other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having trouble to get the command button working and it is
>   probably a simple object oriented problem but I can't see what's wrong.

You wrote:

```
Interface.add_widget(Interface.btn)
```

Have a look at your Interface class--there's no `btn` property defined anywhere. However, prior to that line you constructed a widget named `btn`, so you should write:

```
Interface.add_widget(btn)
```

That leads to another error:

> TypeError: unbound method add_widget() must be called with Interface
>   instance as first argument (got Button instance instead)

When you call a method with a `class name`, it's different than when you call a method with `an instance` of the class:

```
class Dog:
    def bark(self):
        print('woof')

d = Dog()
d.bark()


Dog.bark()


--output:--
woof

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    Dog.bark()
TypeError: unbound method bark() must be called with
   Dog instance as first argument (got nothing instead) #<****HEY!
```

When you call bark() with an instance of the Dog class, python automatically passes the instance as the first argument to the method, which gets assigned to the variable `self`. That doesn't happen when you call the method with the class.

To fix that error, you need to change the line:

```
Interface.add_widget(btn)
```

to:

```
i = Interface()
i.add_widget(btn)
```

Or, more tortuously:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self)

    def bark(self):
        print(self)
        print('woof')

d = Dog()
Dog.bark(d) #<*** Manually pass an instance.

--output:--
woof
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also if anyone have an idea how to use the command button ( btn) to
>   access some of the values stored from the settings it would be great.

The App class has a [config property](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.config), which gives you access to all the settings:

```
class SettingsApp(App):
    ...
    ...
    def onpress_button(self, button):
        print "button touched"
        config = self.config

        print config.getint("example", "numericexample")
        print config.getfloat("example", "numericexample")
        print config.getboolean("example", "boolexample")

        print config.get("example", "stringexample")
        print config.getdefault("example", "non-existent", "hello")

        print config.items('example')


--output:--
button touched
10
10.0
True
PO12345
hello
[('boolexample', 'True'), ('optionexample', 'Analysis type1'), ('stringexample', 'PO12345'), ('numericexample', '10')]
```

Check out the python docs for [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.get) as well as the kivy docs for the [Config](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html#kivy.config.ConfigParser.getdefault) object to see all the methods that are available.